# Responding to custom key presses on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, ios

How do I add a character to a `UITextField` from ASCII or Unicode character set when a custom key is pressed?

Disclaimer: I've seen tons of questions here on Stack Overflow, but I haven't gotten all the information I need to make a hebrew keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your custom key (the simplest case:UIButton) is pressed you append a certain string to uitextfield.text property.

```
uitextfield.text = [uitextfield.text stringByAppendingString:@"yourAsciiString"];
```

the way you convert ascii to strings the same way you will do it in C then you convert that C string to NSString using:

```
- (id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```